# Change SO login to show Stack Overflow icon rather than Stack Exchange icon SEDE

Tags: feature-request, design, data-explorer, login

When I go to [login at SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/), I usually login with Stack Overflow, but the SO login is using the icon from Stack Exchange:

[image]

Could we change that to Stack Overflow's icon ([image])?  It's a small thing, but I think it'd be more comfortable.

Comment: Erm...this is also happening [when joining new accounts.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J2nY.png)

Comment: The logo needs to be added / replaced in the logo-icons.svg: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Content/Img/login-icons.svg